# Why won't the keys automatically bind for my PS3 controller?

Tags: controllers, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

[image: List of connected devices]

[image: lack of key bindings]

I am trying to play with a friend, but the game isn't automatically binding the keys for the controller, despite the fact that it does recognise that there is a controller there. What do I need to do for the game to bind keys automatically for my controller?

Comment: Judging by your screenshot showing "keyboard" I assume you are playing on computer. What operating system/version are you running. In my experience, connecting a PS3 controller to a computer can be significantly difficult. Also, are you using an official PS3 controller, or a knockoff?